# In Django, how to get a query of all objects with a one-to-one relationship with another model?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to refactor some code which has a special kind of user, `LucyGuide`, with a one-to-one relationship to Django's `User` model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class LucyGuide(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod
    def lucy_guide_user_ids(cls):
        return [guide.user_id for guide in cls.objects.all()]
```

In certain use cases, we need all `User`s which have a corresponding `LucyGuide`, which is obtained like so:

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=LucyGuide.lucy_guide_user_ids())
```

This seems rather verbose to me and it seems like there should be a more concise way. Any ideas how to refactor this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is

```
User.objects.exclude(lucyguide=None)
```

This allows the `lucy_guide_user_ids()` method to be dispensed with entirely.